# validating form with autocomplete jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a number of autocomplete list on a couple forms and wondering if there are better way to validating this form

Because some of fields have 1000 rows of data we need to use autocomplete not just selection list.
The problem is not only user can select from the autocomplete list but they can enter manually without selecting from the autocomplete list. Because of this I need to validate the data on submit synchronously to make sure all fields are valid. But since I have to check the fields synchronously it takes more time. I am not sure this is correct way to do it. Or should I just depend on the server side to give me back the error instead? We are developing restful web app with backbone on the front end and .net as server side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066260/jquery-validation-with-custom-method-i-cant-submit-form

Answer (score 1):

What JQuery validate plugin are you using? Assuming you are using some named plugin, the time factor varies depending on the plug-in implementation. You can test it yourself before making a choice.

You said you have to check fields, what do you mean by "check"? Assuming that you mean "check not empty/required" it might not take so much of time as you are anticipating. If you meant "check uniqueness/check something with database" it is totally depending your checking conditional logic and the amount of data against which you are performing this check.

If it was me, I would always implement server side validation. It is better to compromise with a nick of second than to irritate the user with error pages/break soft keys in my database by inserting unwanted inputs.

Some more specifics will help answer this question in "present tense".

Comment: I am using the validation plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ and set remote properly to validate if the specified name really exists on the database.( since user can put value into the autocomplete field manually instead of selecting from the list )

Comment: Believe it or not, I just did it yesterday using the same plugin. As I already said, I implemented server side validation also. There was no significant delay using remote option in that plugin. If you observe any delay, I would predict it to be of the query execution time.

Comment: If you have one or two but what if you have 5 or 6 autocomplete fields in a form and need to validate each fields with server synchronouly

Comment: It should be fine. Go ahead and implement it. If anything fires back, bump this question with your latest findings.