# Jquery Validation with custom method I can't submit form

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jquery validation with custom method. Somehow I need to click twice to submit the form. If you generate onblur event before submit it works.

I have set up a field and click button in the following link with the validation. I set to return true anything you input but I can't submit a form if you don't click twice or generate onblur and click. Am i doing anything wrong here?

http://skoizumi.com/autocomplete/

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("contractorName", function (value, element) {
            console.log( '1');
            console.log( element);
            //$('#searchtext').autocomplete('close');

            var result = false;
            var contractorName = $("#searchtext" ).val();

            //validating the specified field has a valid name
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/autocomplete/testdata.php",
                dataType:"json",
                async: false,                    
                complete: function(){

                },
                success: function(msg)
                {                        
                    console.log( msg);
                    result = true;                         

                }             
            });
            console.log( '2'); 
            return result;
        }, "Specified Contractor doesn't exist");


        $("#myform").validate(
        {
            rules:{
                    searchtext: {
                        contractorName: true    
                    }
            },
            onsubmit: false,
            onkeyup: false
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to find work around. Somehow when I have onfocusout set to true I can't post valid data. With adding the custom method, you don't need to change the server side to have true/false but you can decide on complete function. http://skoizumi.com/autocomplete/index.html if you type in "European Nightjar" you can submit the form otherwise through some error.

Comment: The URL in your answer is broken. Can you try to fix it?

Comment: I updated that source here. http://skoizumi.com/autocomplete/index.html Unfortunately I need to click twice in order to post the data after selecting "European Nightjar"

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous so `result` in your method will always return `false`. Use the built in `remote` method of the plugin.
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options

Comment: OK Let me try with remote option. I guess "async: false" doesn't work

Comment: I set to option but still the same. now I can't even display error message. http://alturl.com/4s7ys I guess either you go with $.ajax or remote it is using $.ajax at the end. how come "async: false" not working?

Comment: Apparently this problem only comes up in firefox.

Comment: use the remote method, you are trying to re-invent a built in method that already works cross browser and has been used on many thousands of sites

Comment: I tried to do with remote but the result is still the same here. http://alturl.com/4s7ys sometimes work and sometimes doesn't work. I didn't use the remote function because it only expects either true/false for server response

Comment: get the validation working before adding autocomplete. Might be running into issues using both

Comment: I gotta removed the autocomplete part, but still have the problem

Comment: server always returns 1 , you have to validate at server and send proper response

Comment: Have set up so that if aaa it returns 1 otherwise returns 0. Unfortunately it does validate as you type but when you click on the link it doesn't validate( valid() ). Also it stops working if you try a couple of times to validate.( just show 1 what ever you put)

Comment: Can you specify which part I am missing?